# Extracting IMEI from mobile from angularJs

Tags: angularjs, mobile-application

I need a IMEI code from a mobile for an application Written in AngularJs,

Application has to access IMEI once its been installed into the device

How can I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be able to access IMEI-like features of your device from an AngularJs/Javascript app only using a mobile framework, like [Cordova/Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/).

With Cordova, for example, you could use this plugin: [cordova-plugin-imei](https://github.com/aquto/cordova-plugin-imei):

```
window.plugins.imei.get(
  function(imei) {
    console.log("got IMEI code:", imei);
  },
  function(err) {
    console.log("error getting IMEI code:", err);
  }
);
```

However, you will not be allowed to access IMEI on iOS, AFAIK...